# Largest Item in Heap

Tags: java, heap

The largest item in a heap must appear in position 1, and the second largest must
be in position 2 or position 3. Give the list of positions in a heap of size 31 where the
kth largest (i) can appear, and (ii) cannot appear, for k=2, 3, 4 (assuming the values to
be distinct).

I am trying to study this for my midterm but its 3AM and I am stuck on this problem in the book as it does not provide a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: -1, as question does not make sense as it is. And shows no prior research

Comment: +1 as it is interesting question nonetheless

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [Heap Implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation) example on Wikipedia, you will see that the third largest can be in position 2 or 3, whichever one the second largest is not, as well as positions 4+5 or 6+7, depending on where the second largest is. Thus, it can be in 2-7.

The fourth largest must then be in any position the third largest can be, plus any position which is a direct child of the third largest. This means it can be anywhere from 2-15.

The following picture is 0-based, as it is an array implementation, so add one for the position.

[image: Picture representation of a heap implemented in an array]