# Determining heap positions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

I'm working on the following problem. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489302/largest-item-in-heap) was asked earlier, but I want to make sure I understood it thoroughly.

"The largest item in a heap must appear in position 1, and the second largest must be in position 2 or position 3. Give the list of positions in a heap of size 31 where the kth largest (i) can appear, and (ii) cannot appear, for k=2, 3, 4 (assuming the values to be distinct)."

I understand that:

2 can be in positions 2 or 3

3 can be in positions 2-7

4 can be in positions 4-15

But I'm confused on where they cannot appear. Would it be that 2 cannot appear in any other positions besides 2 or 3, 3 cannot be in positions other than 2-7, etc? Thank you.

Comment: Well, if your "can appear" list is complete, it follows from logic that all the other positions must be in "cannot appear".

Comment: Note that 4 `can be` in 2 and 3 positions

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clarification, Henry and MBo. I appreciate it!